# Промежуток времени в точности до секунды PHP

Tags: php, время, unixtimestamp

Не нашел ответа в сети и сам не смог сделать, поэтому пришлось обратиться к профессионалам.
В базе хранится время начало создания заявки и время в секундах прошедшее с момента создания до закрытия заявки. Время в unixtimestamp.

Как можно высчитать точное время от начальной даты до настоящей в таком формате: **прошло 3 дня 3 часа 5 минут и 35 секунд**?

Такой вариант:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($row["time"]);
$time_ago = $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

так как он покажет только дату и время начальную а не промежуточную.

Не встречал такой функции в php, поэтому вопрос наверное больше связан с арифметическими действиями, но я не соображу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение:

```
$fromTime = new DateTime;
$fromTime->setTimestamp($row["time"]);
$interval = (new DateTime)->diff($fromTime);

print_r($interval);
```

Спасибо @ScreamingVoices

Comment: `(new DateTime())->diff(new DateTime($row['time']))`

Comment: Решение "покороче" https://repl.it/NihX/0

Comment: @ScreamingVoices просто супер, Вы не против если я поставлю ваше решение в ответ? Спасибо!

Comment: @Владимир не против )

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вам потребуется время в секундах (по вычислению diff'а) и такая вот функция:

```
/**
 * Утилитарная функция для красивого вывода периода (в секундах) в дни, часы, минуты и секунды
 *
 * @param integer $duration Длительность периода в секундах
 * @return string
 */
public static function secondsToTimeString($duration)
{
    $timeStrings = array();

    $converted = [
        'days' => floor($duration / (3600 * 24)),
        'hours' => floor($duration / 3600),
        'minutes' => floor(($duration / 60) % 60),
        'seconds' => ($duration % 60)
    ];

    if ($converted['days'] > 0) {
        $timeStrings[] = $converted['days'] . ' дней';
    }

    if ($converted['hours'] > 0) {
        $timeStrings[] = $converted['hours'] . ' час(ов)';
    }
    if ($converted['minutes'] > 0) {
        $timeStrings[] = $converted['minutes'] . ' минут';
    }
    if ($converted['seconds'] > 0) {
        $timeStrings[] = $converted['seconds'] . ' секунд';
    }

    if(!empty($timeStrings)) {
        return implode(', ', $timeStrings);
    }

    return ' 0 секунд';
}
```

Соответственно если вам нужно еще и в месяцах и годах - добавляйте аналогично.

Answer (score 0):

```
$seconds = time() - $row['time']
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/210100)

Comment: @mymedia объясните тогда уж, почему не является. Формально вглядит как попытка ответа.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, обычно, к кусочкам кода требуется хотя бы небольшое пояснение, чтобы признать ответ полноценным

Comment: @mymedia а по-моему вполне себе попытка ответа.

Comment: Это не попытка ответа, господа, это исчерпывающий ответ на поставленный вопрос.